# SQL: How to INSERT INTO with a value from another table and an Integer

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert into 3 columns. The first columns needs an entry from another table, the second columns just needs a value and the third is NULL. So far I have this:

```
INSERT INTO PAT_CARAC ( NO_PATIENT, NO_CARACTE, DATEEXPIRA)
SELECT pp.NO_PATIENT,'16', NULL  
FROM    PAT_PATIENT pp 
INNER JOIN PAT_CARAC pc ON pp.NO_PATIENT = pc.NO_PATIENT 
WHERE   pp.NO_CLINIQUE = 2;
```

I keep getting a PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the full text of the error? Are there any primary keys on the table you are inserting into?

Comment: Sounds like you need an update.

Comment: You have a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on table `PAT_CARAC` and you are trying to insert either a combination of columns that already exist (in the constraint columns) or a duplicate row from your inserting set.

Comment: I believe what's happening is that the records you are trying to insert into the new table have the same key as records already in that table. Do you know what the key of that table is? Is it NO_PATIENT?

Comment: Thanks for the hints guys. NO_PATIENT is not a unique key but it turns out that if a certain NO_PATIENT already has a specific NO_CARACTE then i cant assign it a second time, hence the error. I still need to tweak a few things but I should be able to figure it out. Thanks again, you guys are super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your PAT_CARAC.NO_PATIENT field is primary key and your query is generating duplicate values

although you can try

INSERT INTO PAT_CARAC ( NO_PATIENT, NO_CARACTE, DATEEXPIRA) 
SELECT DISTINCT pp.NO_PATIENT,'16', NULL
FROM PAT_PATIENT pp INNER JOIN PAT_CARAC pc ON pp.NO_PATIENT = pc.NO_PATIENT WHERE pp.NO_CLINIQUE = 2;